# Execute PHP script on linux with PHP LAMPP service

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, console, lampp

So, I have that question. I've installed xampp on my ubuntu, and I run my web system from there ( `/opt/lampp/htdocs` ). I can open my php web systems from navigator with no troubles. So now I want to run a php script from linux console, like this:

**php -f file.php**

but ubuntu tells me to install **php7.0-cli** or **hhvm** packages to run a php script on console. The real question is, that I've installed lampp running php there. Is there any chance to run a php script on console with the lampp's php service? or I have to install those packages for ubuntu anyway?

Comment: If you want run from the command line, you need the command line interface

Comment: The package `php7.0-cli` refers to the php7 command line interface, maybe you don't have it installed

Comment: Install `php7.0-cli` and provide the absolute path to the file and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run:

```
php -f file.php
```

from the linux terminal you are excecuting the system php enviroment (in ubuntu you install it using apt-get install), if you need run the script with the LAMPP php environment you must run:

/opt/lampp/bin/php -f file.php

Comment: Thanks for your help Cesar. It really worked great in both ways

Answer (score 1):

If you run this command repeatedly, you can set alias by appending the following command in the "~/.bash-aliases" file or by directly running the command in the terminal:

```
alias php='/opt/lampp/bin/php'
```